# How does using color within a list environment change the spacing of the rest of the page?

Tags: spacing, color, lists

The following MWE fits 5 references on the page. As soon as I uncomment the color command (`\myblue`), it only fits four, with nothing else having changed.

Related: one open question that I still have is [Why does a colored line break wrapped in curly spaces take up space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341777/why-does-a-colored-line-break-wrapped-in-curly-spaces-take-up-space) This one has to do with color at the beginning (or end) of a paragraph; here, I use color inside a paragraph inside an environment...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\mysmall{\trivlist\item\small}
\def\endmysmall{\endtrivlist}
% \newcommand{\myblue}{\color{blue}}
\providecommand{\myblue}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \section{Conclusion}
    \lipsum[6]

    \begin{mysmall}
        Black and black and black and black and black and black and black and \myblue{}blue: \lipsum[4]
    \end{mysmall}

    \begin{thebibliography}{3}
        \small
        \bibitem{Bla}Bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla
        \bibitem{Bla}Bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla
        \bibitem{Bla}Bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla
        \bibitem{Bla}Bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla
        \bibitem{Bla}Bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla
        \bibitem{Bla}Bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla and bla
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I have been able to further minimize my problem to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\blue}{}
% \renewcommand{\blue}{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Black and \blue{}blue.
    \end{itemize}

    \section{This moves down when the above is blue.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a documented issue (see `3.7 Possible problems` in color doc, the footnote at bottom of page). Use `\textcolor{blue}{blue}`.

Comment: yes but here at my TeX installation (not fully up-to-date) the document is dated `2017-06-01`... I trigger it from `texdoc color` at the command line.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks! I found this document at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf

Comment: For the record: "There is a different type of problem that will occur for all drivers. Due to certain technical difficulties(^2), it is possible that at points where the colour changes, the spacing is affected. [...] (^2)At least two causes: 1) The presence of a \special <whatsit> prevents \addvspace `seeing' space on the current vertical list, so causing it to incorrectly add extra vertical space. 2) A <whatsit> as the first item in a \vtop moves the reference point of the box."